# how to get data in HTML using PHP?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

there is a currency conversion site at the following address:

```
https://www.tgju.org/currency
```

How can I buy prices like dollars and...?

I have a sample code that finds only one specific class using "file_get_contents"
my code:

```
$content = file_get_contents("https://www.tgju.org/currency");
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content);
$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
$classname = "nf";
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname ')]");
$data1 = $nodes{0}->nodeValue;
```

Thank you for helping me to complete the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the HTML, I see that the US dollar row has the `data-market-row` attribute set to `price_dollar_rl`. And then all the info you want to read
is then stored in some `<td>` cells.

So you could change your XPath query to get all these cells and then take
the value of the one you desire:

```php
<?php

$content = file_get_contents("https://www.tgju.org/currency");
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content) or die('Could not parse the HTML correctly!');
$finder = new DomXPath($dom);

$cells = $finder->query('//tr[@data-market-row="price_dollar_rl"]/td');

print "Found $cells->length <td> cells for US Dollar\n";
foreach ($cells as $index => $cell) {
    print "Cell n°$index: $cell->nodeValue \n";
}

// To get just the first cell:

// A) Just read item 0 from above's query.
print 'Accessing item 0: ' . $cells->item(0)->nodeValue . "\n";

// B) Change your XPath query to get the first <td> with the "nf" class.
$cells = $finder->query(
    '//tr[@data-market-row="price_dollar_rl"]//td[contains(concat(" ",normalize-space(@class)," ")," nf ")][1]'
);
print 'Accessing first td with class "nf" inside dollar row: ' . $cells->item(0)->nodeValue . "\n";
```

This outputs:

```
Found 6 <td> cells for US Dollar
Cell n°0: 490,160 
Cell n°1: (0.3%) 1,460 
Cell n°2: 489,480 
Cell n°3: 491,010 
Cell n°4: Û±Û¶:Û±Û´:Û´Û¶ 
Cell n°5:  

Accessing item 0: 490,160

Accessing first td with class "nf" inside dollar row: 490,160
```

Comment: thanks alot, how to get just "490,180" value?

Comment: @AmirHosseinAghajani : I've updated the code. You can either access one item with `->item(0)` to read the first cell of the row or you could change the XPath query to get only one specific cell.

Comment: It is being done correctly. thank you.